# add service reference only works with localhost wcf service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, service, http-status-code-405

I am trying to host a svc service in my web application and I am trying to connect to it with a simple client application.

When the host is hosted in my own computer and solution, and I run the web application locally, everything works fine, meaning that I can add the reference to the service using `add service reference` in my client solution with `http://localhost:6543/Hello.svc` as the address and when I navigate to the service's url, it shows me the service's information as it should.

But when I publish my website, and I try to add the reference to my service using `add service reference` with `http://myserver.com/Hello.svc` as the address, i get the error message bleow:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://myserver.com/Hello.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'. The
>   request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://myserverc.com/Hello.svc'.
>   The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not
>   Allowed. The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not
>   Allowed. If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the service reference again.

and oddly when I navigate to `myserver.com/Hello.svc`, the browser starts to download the `Hello.svc` file instead of showing the service's details and information.

this is my website's `web.config` file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WithDebug">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="HelloWorldService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="WithDebug">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://myserver/Hello.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain" 
            contract="HelloWorldService.IHelloWorld" />
        <endpoint
            address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I think I am missing something big here, but since I am new to WCF, I don't know what it is.Any help would be appreciated and I am more than happy to issue more details about my project if needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Windows Server are you using? Do you have other Wcf application running on same server?

Comment: I am using a host server running windows server 2008 and .net version 4.0.And no, this is my first service that I am trying to run on this server.Could it be that the server doesn't support WCF?

Comment: Maybe your server doesn't have the framework/wcf activation installed. 
You see this link to certify your server are ok: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blambert/archive/2009/02/13/enable-iis.aspx
You can also test locally on your server if the page opens. On IIS Manager try to browser Hello.svc file

Answer (score 0):

You need to run [ServiceModel registration tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx)

"This command-line tool provides the ability to manage the registration of WCF and WF components on a single machine. Under normal circumstances you should not need to use this tool as WCF and WF components are configured when installed. But if you are experiencing problems with service activation, you can try to register the components using this tool."